# Filtering NaN from an array

Tags: javascript, function, filter, undefined, nan

I'm trying to remove all falsy values from an array.

I know this might not be the optimal solution for this problem but considering that I want to use the switch, is there a way to remove the NaN?

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    arr=arr.filter(removeFalsy);
  return arr;
}

function removeFalsy(val){
    switch(val){
        case false: return false;
        case null: return false;
        case 0: return false;
        case "" :return false;
        case undefined: return false;
        case NaN: return false; // <=== NaN 
        default: return true;
    }
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
//result is: [ NaN ]

bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);
//result is: [ 1, NaN, 2 ]
```

Comment: `NaN == NaN //false` Use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Comment: Anyway, since `NaN` is a falsy value, you could just filter out, all falsy values

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Filter null from an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41346902) and [How to filter() out NaN, null, 0, false in an array (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31925323).

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you just need to keep it simple:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
```

Comment: Oh, now I get why they're called falsy values. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`NaN` is not equal to anything, therefore you need to use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).
As explained in the comments, the global [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is not a good idea.

Thanks for pointing that out.

For an example see [how-do-you-have-a-nan-case-in-a-switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658439/how-do-you-have-a-nan-case-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: @Vld Thanks for the hint. I again did the mistake of assuming core functions would behave intuitively. Changed post accordingly.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I see. I understand the confusion, but `isNaN` should be one of those "known" problems with JS. I've removed my comment but I'll add the important part from it: `isNaN` is very badly named - it doesn't check if the argument passed in is `NaN` (what you'd guess from the name) but whether or not the argument _would be_ `NaN` if converted to a number. Its actual name should be `isThisUsableInAMathematicalExpression`. I guess that's a bit unwieldy, though. Some examples `isNaN("") //false` `isNaN("a") //true` `isNaN([1])//false` `isNaN(["a"]) //true` logic being `+""//0` but `+"a"//NaN`

Answer (score 0):

> The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

Since `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` and `NaN` are all **Falsy** values in JavaScript therefore they will return **false** when tested.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var array = arr.filter(function(val){
    return val;
  });
  return array;
}
```

Only values which **do not return false** will be added to the array.

This question is same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925323/how-to-filter-out-nan-null-0-false-in-an-array-js/39996460#39996460).