# Filter null from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a task to remove false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN elements from an given array. I worked on a solution which removes all except null. Anyone can explain why? Here's the code:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
var notAllowed = ["",false,null,0,undefined,NaN];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for (j=0; j<notAllowed.length;j++) {
         arr = arr.filter(function(val) {
               return val !== notAllowed[j];
              });
  }
 }
return arr;
}

bouncer([1,"", null, NaN, 2, undefined,4,5,6]);
```

Comment: You should be aware that `.filter()` does not remove anything from the Array. It creates a new array with the items removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter() out NaN, null, 0, false in an array (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925323/how-to-filter-out-nan-null-0-false-in-an-array-js)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Well, since all of your values are falsy, just do a `!!` (cast to boolean) check:

```
[1,"", null, NaN, 2, undefined,4,5,6].filter(x => !!x); //returns [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Edit: Apparently the cast isn't needed:

```js
document.write([1,"", null, NaN, 2, undefined,4,5,6].filter(x => x));
```

And the code above removes `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `NaN` just fine.

Comment: And you don't need the `!!`. Just `x=>x` is enough, though @PranavCBalan's way doesn't require creation of a function. `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Yes, your solution works.Thanks for that,but..i'm just starting to learn js so yea..it will help me to understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @squint -- Ahh didnt know that about the case, assumed I needed it. Also didnt know about the sweet `Boolean` rather than function creation... always learning, will make the edit.

Comment: Ok, i got it now. On the freecodecamp platform where I learn it doesnt filter null but if i run the code in the chrome console it does not filter NaN. Thank you all.

Comment: [Javascript comparison table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) is quite handy when it comes to testing boolean equivalences.

Answer (score 35):

It is a problem with `NaN`, because

```
NaN !== NaN
```

read more here: [Testing against `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN).

For filtering the values, you could check for truthyness.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(bouncer([1, "", null, NaN, 2, undefined, 4, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. On the platform where i learn is doesnt filter null...yet in a debugger it doest filter NaN.

Comment: There is *no* problem with `NaN` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

```js
[1, 2, 0, null, "sdf", ""].filter(a=>a)
// filter non null value; remove 0, null and "" (empty quote)
```

```js
console.log([1, 2, 0, null, "sdf", ""].filter(a=>a))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` for *truthy* value check - see demo below:

```js
function bouncer(array) {
  return array.filter(function(e) {
    return e;
  });
}

console.log(bouncer([1,"", null, NaN, 2, undefined,4,5,6]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
 return arr.filter(function(item){
   return !!item;
 });
}

console.log(bouncer([1,"", null, NaN, 2, undefined,4,5,6]));
```