# Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'name' of null. Returning only true values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Refers to the url `https://app.com/api/v1/$ {id}`. Depending on `id`,`API` returns me the response -> `null` or `{name: 'a'}`. The object has the 'name' property. The 'name' property wants to set the state:

```
this.setState ({
    load: this.props.active ['name']
});
```

When I click on items that have the `name` property, they are displayed in the console. When I go to an element that returns 'null' without the 'name' property. I have error: `Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'name' of null`

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            load: null
        }
    }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
        if(prevProps.active !== this.props.active) {
                this.setState({
                    load: this.props.active['name']
                });
        }
    }

  render () {

    return (
      <div >

      </div>
    )
  }
```

My goal is to return only the `true` response.

Something similar to this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 

    if (prevProps.active !== this.props.active) {
      let solution = null;
        if(this.props.active) {
          return solution = this.props.active["name"]
        }
        this.setState({
          load: solution
        });
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, you could check within a component if `this.props.active` exists, so inside of `render`...

```
if (this.props.active) {
  return (
    <div>Your cool detail view with name attribute.</div>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <div>Your empty detail view.</div>
  );
}
```

But if these detail views are a part of some kind of list or collection view, you may want to just skip rendering components for the null values. In that case, in your upstream component you should filter your array of objects ([as described here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346902/filter-null-from-an-array-in-javascript)), and then render your collection with the filtered array.

Answer (score -1):

You could just add it as another conditional in your if statement

```
if(prevProps.active !== this.props.active && this.props.active !== null) {
```