# How to filter null from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I wanted to ask how to filter my array. In this case my array fills with null object and no null object

`[null,{"position":{"lat":50.8999208,"lng":20.6258},"vin":22222}]`

normally if null doesn't appear the array looks like this:

```
`[{"position":{"lat":22.8999208,"lng":22.6258},"vin":11111},{"position":{"lat":50.8999208,"lng":20.6258},"vin":22222}]`
```

But in this case in my programming scenario the first object is nulled and I have to filter this array or maybe copy no-null objects from this array to another array and then compute or error will occur. How should I do it?

Best regards!

Comment: How are you getting this array? From an API?

Comment: `array.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Yes, from my API

Comment: While it may be an issue with the way you are getting the data, Nina's answer should suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter null from an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346902/filter-null-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could filter the array by checking the data.

```js
var array = [null, { position: { lat: 50.8999208, lng: 20.6258 }, vin: 22222 }],
    withoutNull = array.filter(v => v !== null);

console.log(withoutNull);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just check truthy values:

```
truthyValues = array.filter(v => v);
```

```js
let array = [null,{"position":{"lat":50.8999208,"lng":20.6258},"vin":22222}],
    truthyValues = array.filter(v => v);

console.log(truthyValues);
```