# Remove empty elements from an array in JavaScript Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[
{
"stockId":2,"vendorId":1,"vendorCode":"Aya - 01","price":2100
},
null,
null
]

remove the null array from arraylist

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *Hint... The `.filter()` method on arrays in JavaScript can be used to filter the elements of an array.*

Comment: `array.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter null from an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346902/filter-null-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [ { "stockId":2,"vendorId":1,"vendorCode":"Aya - 01","price":2100 }, null, null ]
arr = arr.filter(elem => elem != null)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to remove null or undefined values:

```js
var array = [ { "stockId":2,"vendorId":1,"vendorCode":"Aya - 01","price":2100 }, null, null ];
var filtered = array.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null;
});
  
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove false values, do something like this

```js
var array = [
   { stockId: 2, vendo`enter code here`rId: 1, vendorCode: 'Aya - 01', price: 2100 },
   null,
   null,
];
newArray = array.filter(item => !!item);
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple and concise solution:

```
let newArray = array.filter(Boolean);
```

just pass javascript Boolean (builtin) function inside filter as callback function.